# The Cisco VPN Service has not been started

Tags: windows, cisco-vpn-client

i'm trying to use Cisco VPN client, but i get the error:

> Error 56: The Cisco Systems, Inc. VPN Service has not been started.
>   Please start this service and try again.

[image]

Of course the service *is* started; so that's not very helpful.

It's been working for years (two years), but today i go to use it and it's borken.

Some people have suggested that the **Internet Connection Sharing** service can interfere with Cisco and should be disabled; it already was.

**Edit**: Windows 2000 Professional

Have restarted the service, have rebooted multiple times, have manually run `vpngui.exe`, `vpnclient.exe`, `ipsecdialer.exe`, nothing ever appears.

Comment: I got the same error and i have tried all the recommendations but none of them worked for me. I was wondering if you have find a solution? Thank you,

Comment: Personally I'd just use Shrew VPN...

Comment: @ta.speot.is Personally i'd just use Windows built-in VPN; but the international corporation doesn't care what one developer at an outside vendor thinks.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem (on Windows 7 Professional) and found a way to circumvent it:

1. Stop the Internet Connection Sharing service and change its startup type to "manual"
2. Copy your PCF profiles to the "Profiles" folder of the Cisco VPN Client installation, e.g.:
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\Profiles`
3. Rename the profile(s) you intend to use to have a simple name (no spaces, etc), something like rwc.pcf
4. `cd` to where the vpnclient.exe binary is (e.g.: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN Client)
5. type this: `vpnclient connect rwc` (replace rwc with your profile naturally)
6. The Cisco VPN "User Authentication" windows should pop up now; enter your credentials
7. Done.

Comment: This worked for me, but I still had to start the Cisco Systems, Inc. VPN service after stopping the Internet Connection Sharing service.